# Ajax.. how to hide div being alert

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax and I am doing ok but the issue is that I am having my ajax send some data to the server and then getting some data base.  I would like it to hide the error div and then do the alert but as I run the code the alert shows up firs then the area is set to hide

```
if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
    $('#error').hide('fast');  
    alert("Thanks for submitting.  We will get back to you as asoon as possible.\n\n" + response.result);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to wait for the animation to complete before showing the alert.

Call `alert()` in the `hide()` callback:

```
$('#error').hide('fast', function() { alert(...); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback function, here it goes :

```
if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
    $('#error').hide('fast',function()
    {
         alert("Thanks for submitting.  We will get back to you as asoon as possible.\n\n" + response.result);
    });          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { alert('...') },100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a callback to hide(), which happens after the animation is completed:

```
$('#error').hide('fast', function() {
    alert("Your alert string");
});
```

Read more from the official docs:
http://api.jquery.com/hide/